# Can I use event data from previous calls in a batch?

Tags: polkadot-js, pallet-proxy

Considering the following scenario, is it possible to execute all calls in a batch and therefore sign only once using `utility.batchAll` in polkadot.js?

1. Create `PureProxy` from account A
2. Assign account X as anyProxy for the newly created `PureProxy`
3. De-assign account A as anyProxy

To execute 2 and 3 we need the address generated in step 1 which is accessible via the `proxy.PureCreated` event. Is there a way to pipe this event data to the following calls in the batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know that is not something that `batchAll` enables, nor any of the other extrinsics exposed in `pallet_utility`.

Though, it doesn't seem like a trivial approach, as what would happen if the first call emits an event containing more values than what the following call is expecting as parameters, or what happens in the scenario of a call emitting more than one event.

After all, events are there to let users/clients know that something has happened on chain. I don't think there is an approach that saves you from signing more than 1 call if that exact flow is not covered in an extrinsic.